# Redux not showing result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i need help with redux toolkit, i'm using redux to fetch one array of objects but this not happen bellow is my redux code and get api.

**GET API**

```
export const getProductsApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${gateway.url}/products`,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

**MY REDUX ACTION**

```
import {
  getProductsPending,
  getProductsSuccess,
  getProductsFailed,
} from "../../slices/get-products";
import { getProductsApi } from "../../../api/get-products";

export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch(getProductsPending());
  try {
    const response = await getProductsApi();
    const data = response.data;
    console.log('products redux here', data);
    dispatch(getProductsSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getProductsFailed(error));
  }
};
```

**REDUX SLICE**

```
const getProductsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "getProducts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getProductsPending: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.error = "";
    },
    getProductsSuccess: (state, action: PayloadAction<Product[]>) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.products = action.payload;
      state.error = "";
    },
    getProductsFailed: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.error;
      state.products = [];
    },
  },
});

const { reducer, actions } = getProductsSlice;

export const { getProductsPending, getProductsSuccess, getProductsFailed } =
  actions;

export default reducer;
```

**REDUX STORE**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import getProductsReducer from "../redux/slices/get-products";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: getProductsReducer,
  },
});
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
export default store;
```

in my browser console when is to appear the data, data appear so[image]

whit my products array empty, and i don't know where is my error because anothers redux i made, i make like this and work correctly.
I appreciate every help to solve my question.

using redux tookit

Comment: You actually not posted same code of your slice for store.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with API response you have json response with getProductsApi and again you are accessing it's value with data object "response.data" cross check the endpoint is returning the correct data structure.